# Rails 3 - How to create custom html components that are treated with CRUD operations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html, ruby-on-rails-3.1, html5-canvas

I'm using Rails 3 to create a project that will need a model called Sketch.  I've already created a model, controller, and migration to handle Sketch - so far it just creates a 'sketch' object with a name for each sketch.

My problem is that I need to be able to attach an html5 canvas to each sketch object when it is created (or remove it when it is destroyed).

Since 'canvas' is not a datatype that will be stored in the database (like 'string', 'integer', or 'datetime'), how do I go about creating custom html components such as this that need to be treated like any other datatype in a Rails app?

I'm assuming that you would need to add the html components to a Model method and use a callback - like after_save - to initiate the component.  But I'm not sure at all how to do this.

Not sure if I'm describing this well enough, so here is a very simple mockup:
[image]

I have the Raphael Javascript library in mind for the component that will do the sketching - if that helps.

If you can point me to any tutorials on this subject that would be great.

Comment: I made a simple diagram that shows my current index view for the Sketch model along with a canvas component similar to what I'm trying to do.  Sorry if I'm not using the right terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 canvases are rendered in the browser, not on the server where your ruby code is actually executed. Therefore I think it's safe to say that what you're asking isn't possible (at least in the way the question is phrased).

Instead you'll need to work with HTML, CSS and Javascript in your view to get the canvas working.

[Canvas Tutorial / Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334216/canvas-tutorial-reference)

Hope this helps.

(On a related note, it's also considered a bad practice to mix view-related concepts in with your models.)

Comment: Ok thanks - I'm still pretty new to rails and haven't attempted anything like this before.  I'll take a look at those tutorials.